# 'Header' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I am new to reactjs. I have created a application and trying to load header component inside the app.js. When i try to load the Header component it show throws warning error in command prompt as

```
./src/components/Header.jsx
Line 2 'Header' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Also throws error in the browser when i run the application

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

Check your code at App.js:24

I have added a file ".eslintrc" in the root and added below code to that

```
{
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
  }
},
"rules": {

}
}
```

So far nothing works. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Try using `Header`?

Comment: You want to try like "import Header from './components/Header'" ? If Yes, i am already using Header only.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem : you import it but never use it. Add it to the return value of your render function.

Comment: `export default class Header extends React.Component { }` and then you have to import your file to the actual file you are returning the value.

Comment: @Ozan - It works perfectly. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Please rename `Header.jsx` to `Header.js`

Be sure to put following line of code on top of your App.js:

```
import {Header} from '/src/components/Header.jsx'
```

be sure to put `export` in front of `class Header {..}`

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: app.js is already inside src folder. i have tried adding export like below nothing works same error.

    import React, {Component} from 'react'
export
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>Your header</div>);
  }
}

Comment: The issue should be solved, try hard reload. by the by there is no need to import component like,
    `import React, {Component} from 'react'`, it may produce another warning.